# How to capture all numbers outside of parentheses?

Tags: php, regex, numbers, preg-match, preg-split

If I have a string like this:

```
$string = "number: 20 (10 30 10 zzz) 40 60";
```

How do I match all numbers outside the parentheses?

I would like to get only

```
20,40,60
```

Comment: I will give you a hint. Replace stuff inside `()` with blank and then match remaining digits.

Comment: Quick and dirty you could explode(" ",$string); and just grab positions 0, 5 and 6

Comment: You could skip them if the parenthesis are always matching, `\([^)]+\)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\d+`.

Comment: You could solve this in a myriad of ways, however remember that regex can not match balanced parentheses as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns). So unless you wont ever have more than one set of parentheses, you should reconsider your approach.

Comment: Regular Expressions in practice differs from theories. If you were familiar with recursions then you'd know it's possible in PCRE. @Olian04

Comment: @revo I'm aware that some regex implementations do support feature outside the core 'regular expressions' definition. However 'regular expression' can not match balanced parentheses. (I should also mention that i haven't used PCRE)

Comment: Since OP struggles with the problem in a programming language scope, Regular Expressions in theories doesn't apply much. `php` uses `PCRE`, the most well-featured regex engine, in order to work with them which out of the box supports recursions as well. @Olian04

Comment: @revo As i said, i havent used PCRE. But thank you for the clarification. The more you know :)

Comment: You only need to get the first sentence of last comment of mine. No problem with not being familiar with `PCRE` at all. @Olian04

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `preg_split()` approach:

Input:

```
$string = "number: 20 (10 30 10 zzz) 40 60";
```

One-liner ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/j60by9/7)):

```
var_export(preg_split('/ |number: |\([^)]*\)/', $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '20',
  1 => '40',
  2 => '60',
)
```

This pattern will explode on:

- every space
- every `number:`
- every parenthetical expression

---

Edits:

This pattern also works with `preg_split()`: `/[ a-z:]+|\([^)]*\)/i` It is slightly faster.

...

chris85's commented pattern for `preg_match()` is correct.  I have optimized it by reversing the alternatives: `\d+|\([^)]+\)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`

Comment: @Sah Might you mark this page as resolved?